# Setting a CRON to be run on every 1st and the 3rd Monday

Tags: shell-script, scheduled-tasks, cron, plesk

I need to set up a CRON job to be scheduled in

**every 1st and the 3rd Monday** of every Month.

I'm using the *Plesk* control panel for setting these as follows.

[image]

Currently CRON runs successfully, however on **every Monday**. Which isn't my requirement.

Also referred this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683387/cron-run-every-2nd-and-4th-saturday-of-the-month
Then the CRON runs on 1-7,15-21 fourteen times.

Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 6):

I recently scheduled the job, like you had/have. In similar case, what I do is find out the dates of month that usually fall on day of week, for example 1st Monday usually fall between 1-7 and 3rd Monday falls in between 15-23. 
Hence, following crontab should work for you

```
30 3 1-7,15-22 * * [`date +\%u` = 1] &&  <job>
```

above cronhjob gets schedule for each day between 1-7 and 15-23 dates of month, however, gets executed only when the day of week is 1 (Monday).